# Implementing vectors to speed up pitch calculation (numpy.arctan2 and np.sqrt)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Trying to calculate pitch information for the data using 2 data points

**Function used**

```
def pitch_calculate(x,y,z):
  x_Buff = float(x)
  y_Buff = float(y)
  z_Buff = float(z)
  pitch = np.arctan2((- x_Buff) , np.sqrt(y_Buff * y_Buff + z_Buff * z_Buff)) * 57.3
return pitch
```

**Pandas Apply**

```
df['PITCH'] = df.apply(lambda x: pitch_calculate(x['x'], x['y'], x['z'] ), axis=1)
```

How do I implement vector calculation for this ?

Comment: @cs95. And despite all that, it's what he did after the colon that have him the error.

Comment: Why don't you just pass in the entire column for each input to the function. No need to apply anything. The numpy calculation is already vectorized.

Comment: @MadPhysicist could you point to the error you are referring to please ?

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Python is very space sensitive.

Comment: yeah it is alright in my code. just how it is when i paste it here. i forgot to indent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['PITCH'] = np.arctan2(-df.x, np.sqrt(df.y * df.y + df.z * df.z)) * 57.3
```

Comment: thank u! 5 minutes now become : 1.18 s ± 11.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)